# Relationship between state transitions and population transitions

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I have $M$ identical particles which each have $K$ states. They each evolve independently in Markov chains with transition probability matrix $\pi$. My question is if I want to look at the populations of each of the $K$ states rather than the states directly, then how does the transition matrix for the populations relate to $\pi$?

Comment: Just wanna make sure I understand: Let $N_j(t) = $ the population of a state $j$ at time $t$.  Then $N_j(t+1)$ does not depend just on $N_j(t)$, but depends on how the rest of the population (the other $M- N_j(t)$ particles) are distributed in other states as well.  In other words $N_j(t)$ is not a stand-alone Markov Chain.  The vector $(N_1(t), N_2(t), \dots, N_K(t))$ would describe the full state and that is a Markov Chain.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct

Comment: Well then the full state must be the $K$-vector, and the state space is huge: By stars and bars, there are $N= {M + K -1 \choose M}$ ways to place $M$ identical particles into $K$ states, so $N$ such vectors, and your transition matrix is $N\times N$.  Not only that: there are many, many ways to transition from state $v$ to $v'$.  Is that your real question, i.e. for given $v, v'$ what is $P(v \to v')$?

Comment: Yes, I want to reduce the dimensionality of the problem by focusing on the population instead of the exact states because as you have said, the dimensionality of the full space goes like $K^M$ but the dimensionality of the populations is $M+K-1$ choose $M$. The problem is that I only know the transition matrix from $\vec{v}$ to $\vec{v}'$. I want to know the transition matrix from $\vec{N}$ to $\vec{N}'$

Comment: We're using the variables to mean different things, and it's my fault that I didn't define what I meant by $v$.  Anyway, say $M=10, K=3$ and you're looking to find e.g.  $P((0,8,2) \to (2,3,5))$ and all such?

Comment: Yes, and you are given $\pi$ where $\pi_{ij} = P(v'=j|v=i)$. Basically you are given the transition probabilities of the particle at the next time step, $v'$ being in state $i$ given that the particle now, $v$, is in state $j$.

Comment: If there is additional structure, like a particle can only transition from $i$ to $i \pm 1$, then the counting is much easier.  If not...  this seems very hard to track.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately there is not